# How to retrieve the path of files from a folder into a text file with a python script?

Tags: python

```
import shutil
import os

def get_files():
    source = os.listdir("/output_folder/sample/cufflinks/")
    destination = "output_folder/assemblies.txt"
    for files in source:
        if files.with("transcripts.gtf"):
            shutil.move(files,destination)
```

I want to retrieve `transcripts.gtf` files from `"/output_folder/sample/cufflinks/"` to `assemblies.txt`. Is the above code correct or not. Please help me out. Thank you !!

Comment: What makes you think it's not right? How does it behave differently from what you expect?

Comment: Why don't you test it out and tell us if it works the way you expect it to?

Comment: you have code Review for reviewing your code! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's almost correct. I can give you the answer, but I'll work you through it. What do you expect this line to do `if files.with("transcripts.gtf"):`? Try to add more comments to your code to make it obvious, what your intentions are.

Comment: @e-nouri [codereview.se] is for "my code works, help me make it better!" And not for "does this thing even work?"

Comment: Still a code review, debugging if you want ! still a review, see my response below!

Comment: it will search for the transcripts.gtf files for which i need the paths and copy them into a text file. @tommy

Comment: This question would be closed as off-topic, so regardless of whether or not you consider it "a code review", you shouldn't recommend questions that would be closed on that target site. If this question isn't a good fit for SO, explain why and recommend changes that would make it a better fit for SO. It doesn't belong on [codereview.se].

Comment: @nhgrif He, I already voted to close the question on CR before even seeing it here actually.

Comment: @e-nouri code review has a rule that the code must be working code, if the author doesn't know if it's correct (same as working in mine eye's). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers

Comment: just i asked this in code review. i got a msg saying it doesn't belong there

Comment: See my response, also you are trying to move a file inside a text file ?! doesn't make sens! you want to copy the content or just move the file in the folder ?!

Comment: I just want to copy the path of the files from the folder into the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) :

```
import os
import shutil
from os.path import join

destination =  "/output_folder/assemblies.txt" # Absolute path, or use join
folder_to_look_in = "/output_folder/sample/cufflinks/" # Absolute folder path, or use join
for _, _, files in os.walk(folder_to_look_in):
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.endswith("transcripts.gtf"):
            try:
                # 'a' will append the data to the tail of the file
                with open(destination, 'a') as my_super_file:
                    my_super_file.write(file_name)
            except OSError as e:
                print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
```

Comment: I don't want to move the file. Just the path of the files should be given into the text file.

Comment: for eg: the text file should contain like this /sample1/transcripts.gtf
/sample2/transcripts.gtf
/sample3/transcripts.gtf
/sample4/transcripts.gtf
/sample5/transcripts.gtf
/sample6/transcripts.gtf

Comment: There you go ! Please next time try to get something working on your own, it is the best way to improve your coding skills !

Comment: @user3351523 It would have been super helpful with the example you provide here in your original question. Good questions in general receive good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally understand what you are trying to achieve. Use the [glob.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) function:

```
import glob
destination = "output_folder/assemblies.txt"
source = '/output_folder/sample/cufflinks/*/*transcripts.gtf'
with open(destination, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(glob.glob(source))+'\n')
```

`f.write('\n'.join(glob.glob(source))+'\n')` is the equivalent of:

```
s = ''
for path in glob.glob(source):
    s += '{}\n'.format(path)
f.write(s)
```

Comment: W will wipe the file if you run the script 2 times

Comment: @e-nouri That is correct. You can use `'a'` instead of `'w'`, if you want to append.

Comment: @tommy what does this tell f.write('\n'.join(glob.glob(source))+'\n')

Comment: @user3351523 I updated the answer with an explanation.